# meteor: add some value to nested documents

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to add a value to a nested schema:

```
groups = new SimpleSchema({
    title:      { type: String, optional: true },
    element:    { type: [elements], optional: true }
});

elements = new SimpleSchema({
    description:{ type: String, optional: true },
    anything:    { type: String, optional: true }
});

MongoDB.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    title:      { type: String },
    slug:       { type: String, unique: true },
    language:   { type: String, defaultValue: "en" },
    group:      { type: [groups], optional: true },
}));
```

Now I want to add just a new element-description to an existing entry in the DB. I tried this, but it doesn't work.

`Uncaught Error: When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator`

```
var newElement = {
  description: 'insert this as a new element description'
};
MongoDB.update({ _id: Id }, { $push: { 'group.element': newElement }}, function(error) { if(error) console.warn(error); });
```

Is it correct to use 'group.element' as a $push-parameter?

**Update**

I forgot the index of group: `$push: { 'group.0.element': newElement }`
Also I have to define elements before groups in the schema.

Comment: did you try to $set parameter?

Comment: What packages do you have installed? I'm getting an error: `Error: Invalid definition for slug field`